# BlackRaccoon Check if file exist

Tags: ios, ios7, upload, blackraccoon

I'm using BlackRaccoon to upload a file within a server.
Prior to upload I'd like to understand if it is possible to check if the file that I upload is present or not!.
Is it possible?
Thank you,
Vincenzo

Comment: [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:filepath] doesn't work?

Comment: Sorry check on FTP Server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could maybe use the List Directory Function

```
listDir = [[BRRequestListDirectory alloc] initWithDelegate: self];  

listDir.path = @"/home/user/newdirectory/";
listDir.hostname = @"192.168.1.100";
listDir.username = @"yourusername";
listDir.password = @"yourpassword";

[listDir start];
```

then on the received list there is a

```
- (BOOL)fileExists:(NSString *)fileNamePath;
```

option.

Pass this the fileName to check whether your file already exists in the Directory.